# Query Array of IDs in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got an error message when I tried to query array of IDs in controller action. Here is the error message: string[] does not contain a definition for "contains" and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.contains, Guid)' requires a receiver of type ''.
My code is:

```
public ActionResult GetNews(string[] IDs)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {  
        var qry = db.News.Where(x => IDs.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
        ...
    }
}
```

There is a red line under IDs. IDs is an array passed from View. ID is Guid datatype. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just pass an Guid[] to the action method instead of string[]?

Comment: I would not expect a `string[]` to contain a `Guid`.

Comment: It work work with an actual list of IDs instead of your string array: `GetNews(string[] IDs)` would become `GetNews(List<int> IDs)`...

Answer (score 1):

**You need to set id in one list then after you use it same as my code**

```
public ActionResult GetNewsByID(List<int> IDs)
 {
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {     
        var news= db.News.Where(x => IDs.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh, it works when I change the string[] to Guid[]. Thanks for the responses.